# What's the maximum necessary size in pixels for a video for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, resolution, adobe-flash, mp4

I'm exporting MOVs from Flash, then converting them to mp4 with Handbrake. The video will scale to the screen size, but I would prefer it to scale down, rather than  scale up.

So, what are the optimum pixel width and height of a MOV/mp4 for iPhones? By "optimum", I mean the maximum needed to display 1:1 on the highest definition iPhone screen.

I know iPhone screen sizes have changed with each new iPhone, and screen sizes come in [points, rendered pixels, physical pixels and physical devices](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions). But hopefully in the end there's max X-px x Y-px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently biggest iPhone is the iPhone 7 plus. It has a 5.5-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit widescreen.

- In landscape mode it has a 1920-by-1080-pixel resolution at 401 ppi.
- In portrait mode it has a 1080-by-1920-pixel resolution at 401 ppi.

Which is the equivalent of a full HD movie.